# Single query: fetch non empty folders

Tags: soql, relationships

I'd like to know if it is possible to write a single SOQL query to pull all the Document Folders (I need only folder id) which are not empty.

Comment: can you not query document object and check if folderid != null on the document object,  and add the folderid(s) to a set and get Id's that have atleast one doc attached to them ?

Comment: Did you try `select ID from folder where ID in (select folderID from document)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE Id IN (SELECT FolderId FROM Document)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)